# successful install of composer, but message shows: The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly

Tags: composer-php, environment-variables

I have installed composer on a Ubuntu vagrant box, running `php 7.0` (which was just installed prior to this).  Trying simply `composer`, or the full path `php /usr/local/bin/composer` both result in the following error:

```
The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for 
composer to run correctly
```

I am unfamiliar with which env variable to set (or both), what value it should be set to, or where it should be set/declared!  I've searched quite a few forums including github, but I'm not seeing this information.  Appreciate your help.

[image: error after composer install]

**UPDATE:** Also tried this, same message:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following worked for me, successfully allowing me to see the composer output:

```
export COMPOSER_HOME="$HOME/.config/composer";
composer
```

Note that I was able to just run `composer` in the project folder, didn't need to use the full path.

REFERENCE: https://github.com/consolidation/cgr/issues/10

(javi-dev commented on Feb 24)

Comment: Thanks, don't know where were from you guys get these solutions. :)

Comment: Where do these lines go? I'm trying to run the composer installer php script, and I get the same message because neither HOME nor COMPOSER_HOME is set in the environment. This "solution" defines what COMPOSER_HOME should contain, assuming we can guess what $HOME is, but where is this normally set? Do we add a setenv statement at the top of every composer script?  Is it set in the PHP configuration? I know these things are possible, but what is normal/best practice?

Comment: You could put it into `~/.bashrc` for example.